# Couldn't be able to replace multiple characters in String

Tags: java, string

I have a certain string in which I want to replace all occurrence of character with some other characters, for example,

this is the paragraph that I have,

```
bv xfeu xeelppuq vx t eupvtbf obfc, vktv bi ku twztds ofuz vku pbckv
vbnu vx hucbf uaupdvkbfc; bi ku ofuz zkx zupu vku pbckv juxjwu vx
wbsvuf vx, tfq zkxn vx taxbq; tfq, thxau tww, bi ku twztds ofuz zktv
zts vku nxsv bnjxpvtfv vkbfc vx qx, ku zxlwq fuaup itbw bf tfdvkbfc
ku nbckv lfqupvtou.
```

These is another String (String1) `ETAONRISHDLFCMUGYPWBVKJXQZ`

and this is the 3rd String (String2) `UVXFTKBSQPZNLCWDEIJHOAMGYR`

What I want to do is pick one character from `String1` one by one and replace it with the one character in `String2` in my paragraph.

For example,

All `E` must be replaced with `U` in paragraph, and all `T` should be replaced with `V` and so on. For this reason I have coded the following program,

```
String paragraph = "bv xfeu xeelppuq vx t eupvtbf obfc, vktv bi ku twztds ofuz vku pbckv
    vbnu vx hucbf uaupdvkbfc; bi ku ofuz zkx zupu vku pbckv juxjwu vx
    wbsvuf vx, tfq zkxn vx taxbq; tfq, thxau tww, bi ku twztds ofuz zktv
    zts vku nxsv bnjxpvtfv vkbfc vx qx, ku zxlwq fuaup itbw bf tfdvkbfc
    ku nbckv lfqupvtou."

String s1 = "ETAONRISHDLFCMUGYPWBVKJXQZ"
String s2 = "UVXFTKBSQPZNLCWDEIJHOAMGYR"
```

Now I am replacing them like this,

```
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                    paragraph = paragraph.replace(s1.charAt(x), s2.charAt(x));
                }
```

All `E` in `paragraph` should be replaced with `U`, all `T` with `V` and so on, but the output before and after the for loop is the same.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters in `paragraph` are in **lower case**. The characters in `s1` and `s2`, in contrast, are in **upper case**. `e` and `E` are not the same character, so `replace` doesn't find and replace `e` when you search for `E`.

If you make the characters in `s1` and `s3` lower case, it works:

[**Live Copy**](http://ideone.com/9jwm0G)

```
String paragraph = "bv xfeu xeelppuq vx t eupvtbf obfc, vktv bi ku twztds ofuz vku pbckv vbnu vx hucbf uaupdvkbfc; bi ku ofuz zkx zupu vku pbckv juxjwu vx wbsvuf vx, tfq zkxn vx taxbq; tfq, thxau tww, bi ku twztds ofuz zktv zts vku nxsv bnjxpvtfv vkbfc vx qx, ku zxlwq fuaup itbw bf tfdvkbfc ku nbckv lfqupvtou.";

String s1 = "etaonrishdlfcmugypwbvkjxqz";
String s2 = "uvxftkbsqpznlcwdeijhoamgyr";
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
    paragraph = paragraph.replace(s1.charAt(x), s2.charAt(x));
}
System.out.println(paragraph);
```

Or, of course, make the characters in `paragraph` upper case.

Comment: It works, but why it start replacing character with different characters then it supposed to be ? for example if i run the loop 1 time, all `e` are replaced with `u` , but if the loop is running `26` times, it is replacing `e` with some other character instead of `u`, this shouldn't happen because once it is replaced, it wouldn't find any other occurence of that ccharacter

Comment: So what you want to do is replace it once and for all?

Comment: @RileyWillow: That's a *different* question from the one I answered ("why doesn't anything change?"); you may want to post a new question. The reason it does that is that's what you've told it to do: On the first pass, it replaces `e` with `u`. Then, on the 15th pass, it replaces `u` with `w`. If you want that not to happen, you'll have to build up a separate string (probably in a `char[]`) unless it's possible to organize your replacements so that the character you're replacing with (each character from `s2`) doesn't appear subsequently in `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change them once and for all and not change the value at every loop, here is a method using a `StringBuilder` appending the new chars and creating a new `String` object.

```
    String paragraph = "bv xfeu xeelppuq vx t eupvtbf obfc, vktv bi ku twztds ofuz vku pbckv vbnu vx hucbf uaupdvkbfc; bi ku ofuz zkx zupu vku pbckv juxjwu wbsvuf vx, tfq zkxn vx taxbq; tfq, thxau tww, bi ku twztds ofuz zktv zts vku nxsv bnjxpvtfv vkbfc vx qx, ku zxlwq fuaup itbw bf tfdvkbfc ku nbckv lfqupvtou.";
    String s1 = "etaonrishdlfcmugypwbvkjxqz";
    String s2 = "uvxftkbsqpznlcwdeijhoamgyr";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < paragraph.length() ; i++){
        String temp = String.valueOf(paragraph.charAt(i));

        if (s1.contains(temp)){
            sb.append(s2.charAt(s1.indexOf(temp)));
        } else{
            sb.append(temp);
        }
    }

    String output = sb.toString();
```

And here is the value of `output` :

```
ho gnuw guuziiwy og v uwiovhn fhnl, oavo hb aw vjrvps fnwr oaw ihlao ohtw og qwlhn wxwipoahnl; hb aw fnwr rag rwiw oaw ihlao mwgmjw jhsown og, vny ragt og vxghy; vny, vqgxw vjj, hb aw vjrvps fnwr ravo rvs oaw tgso htmgiovno oahnl og yg, aw rgzjy nwxwi bvhj hn vnpoahnl aw thlao znywiovfw.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your string `s1` and `s2` to lower case. The `paragraph` has characters in lower case while the strings `s1` and `s2` have characters in upper case.